# Python Graphviz: difference between two codes

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am new to Python graphviz.

I was going through some tutorials and found out that there are two ways to generate a graph.

```
import graphviz 
dot_digraph = """
digraph graphname {
    rankdir=LR;
     a -> b -> c -> e ->f;
     b -> d;
}
"""
```

```
digraph1 = graphviz.Digraph
digraph1.node("A")
digraph1.node("B")
digraph1.node("C")
print(digraph1.source)
```

What is the difference between these two codes other than the graph generated?

First one uses text and second one uses object.

Comment: Without a complete MWE it is hard to tell exactly, but the first is a complete dot file that can be handed to `dot` (implicitly or explicitly) or given to a library function that processes dot files, the second part are just the components that by means of methods of `graphviz.Digraph` are made to a dot file that is handed to `dot` or directly to an underlying library for processing.

Comment: @albert thank you for the answer. so what you are saying is that first one is a dot file and second is written for graphviz.Digrah right? so second one is not written as dot language

Comment: More or less. The first is indeed directly in the dot syntax, the second is written in an python interface layer on top of dot (so one does not have to deal with all nifty gritty details and also can use it to easily generate a graph or dot file) on the bottomline there is probably still a dotfile used to generate graph.